# npm request vs. XMLHttpRequest for simple GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, xmlhttprequest

Up until now, I've always used the plain old XMLHttpRequest for GET requests, e.g.,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

I now came across [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and saw that it's tremendously popular. Its equivalent

```
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
})
```

is a tad bit shorter, and I was wondering if there are any more significant benefits to it. Error handling perhaps?

Comment: don't the two run in different places? how could they be interchangeable?

Comment: Are you writing server-side code or client-side code?

Comment: @SLaks This particular one is for a browser extension, so I'd count that as front-end. How does that make a difference though?

Comment: Learn about Node.js (which is not what you're doing) or Browserify.

Comment: I believe the way you are using the XMLHTTP get request is synchronous vs. the request method is asynchronous. That is what I was always lead to believe.

Comment: @SLaks I do use browserify already. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Four_lo The third argument `true` makes the XmlHttpRequest asynchronous, cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open().

Comment: if it ain't broke, don't replace it.

Comment: Use whichever one makes the most sense in your usecase. I'd consider including an entire module into your code to perform a single XHR request a bit overkill, but if you do far more than just this one, then it *could* be helpful. Could also be useful if your code is meant to run both on the server and the client since on the server `window.XMLHttpRequest` doesn't exist.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't know that `XMLHttpRequest` is from `window`; this will be the reason why request is so popular, too. If you promote your reply to an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: If the browser extension you are writing is exclusively for browsers that support the Fetch API, that is worth considering.

Comment: I don't feel i know enough about the request module to provide an answer I can stand behind.

Comment: if you need portability, it's easier to add XMLHttpRequest to node than it is to add request to a browser...

Comment: @dandavis I don't need portability really, but I've already added request to browser. It's really easy with browserify.

Comment: What i'm unsure of with request is it's browser support. I don't see any mention of XHR within it's src, so i have no idea what it's using to implement the functionality. I wouldn't suggest a module for client-side use if i knew that it didn't support IE 10+.

Comment: right, i'm just saying that two libs and a build step to the browser code is more than a single require("XMLHttpRequest") is to node, so if you needed homogenization, it would make sense to take the simple approach that results in code more folks can maintain. just my $0.02...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a browser, `XMLHttpRequest` is already built in so you should only get some other library that builds on top of it if that library offers you particular features that you find useful and are worth the extra download.  In the interest of keeping web pages as lean as possible, I wouldn't just go loading new modules for the heck of it if you have something built in that already works just fine.  So, that's purely a judgement for yourself if browserify and the request module is worth what you're getting.  The request module is a nice lean and flexible interface so it has that going for it.

On node.js, the is no actual `XMLHttpRequest` object built-in so anything that offers that interface is taking a module like the `http` module and then building a new `XMLHttpRequest` interface on top of it.  The `request` module is also building on the `http` module, but it's doing it in a much lighterweight and simpler to use way (my opinion).  So, of the three choices: 1) code yourself with the http module, 2) Load the XMLHttpRequest module and code to that interface or 3) Load the request module and code to that, you can form your own opinion about what is the cleanest and simplest way to code.  There is less issue with loading new modules server-side (since they're generally just loaded once from local hard disk at startup).  I personally find the `request()` module to be really simple and very functional so that's what I use to make server-side http requests.  The XMLHttpRequest object has never seemed like a great interface in the browser so I have no interest in using it server-side.

One advantage of the `request()` module is that it follows the node.js async callback convention which means you can very easily use it with promises (one call to something like the Bluebird `.promisifyAll()` on the module will get you promisified versions of the whole interface) which many (myself included) find very useful for managing async responses cleanly.  The `XMLHttpRequest` object does not follow such a convention so a wrapper would have to be put around it to cleanly use it with promises (on the client-side, `jQuery.ajax()` is an example of such a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`).

If one was looking for the exact same interface on both client and server, I'd probably go with the `request()` module just because it seems cleaner to me than the XMLHttpRequest interface (my personal opinion).